# Como acessar chaves em dicionário Python com o mínimo de for possível?

Tags: python-3.x, loop, dicionário

Quero aprender a deixar meu código cada vez mais enxuto para facilitar sua compreensão e diminuir o tempo de execução e utilização de recursos computacionais.

Hoje peço ajuda para conseguir diminuir a quantidade de "loop for" ao percorrer um dicionário com várias chaves encadeadas.

Dicionário:

```
menu_groups = {
    "1": {
        "GERENCIA": {
            1: "IDENTIFICAÇÃO DO HOST",
            2: "ADD USUÁRIOS",
            3: "CHAVE SSH",
            4: "CHAVE SSH",            }
    },
    "2": {
        "INTERFACES_ETHERNET": {
            1: "ADD INERFACE LOOPBACK",
            2: "ADD INTERFACES DE CONEXAO COM ISP",
            3: "ADD LISTA DE INTERFACES PARA NAT",
            4: "ATRIBUIÇÃO DOS IPS PARA LAN E LOOPBACK",
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "FIREWALL": {
            1: "FILTROS",
            2: "NAT",
            3: "MANGLE",
        }
}
```

Esse 'dict' tem uma chave principal como se fosse um 'id' e grupos de configurações com seus respectivos 'comandos'.

Código que estou usando pra exibir a relação de comandos de determinado grupo de configurações

```
for key in sorted(menu_groups):
    for key1 in sorted(menu_groups[key]):
        for key2, value2 in sorted(menu_groups[key][key1].items()):
            print(f'{key2} - {value2}')
```

Qual a outra forma de percorrer esse tipo de *dict* sem tantos *loop for*?

Obrigado!

Comment: Se o dicionário tem 3 níveis (um dicionário que contém outros dicionários, que por sua vez contém outros dicionários), e vc quer cada subnível ordenado, não tem muito como fugir de 3 loops aninhados. A sugestão abaixo de usar recursão é válida, mas acho que só vale a pena se vc não sabe a quantidade de níveis. Se vc sabe que sempre são 3 (ou qualquer outro valor fixo), não vejo problema em ter um `for` dentro do outro, é a solução mais simples e não vejo necessidade de nada mirabolante

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão!
No caso atual são 6 níveis, mas a ideia é usar o modo  low code pra facilitar a vida do usuário, então, caso o ADM de Sistema crie novos níveis terá que ser implementado novos 'for', ao longo do tempo o desempenho da aplicação poderá ser comprometido.

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa para percorrer um dicionario com varias chaves encadeadas sem usar tantos loops for é utilizar a recursao. A recursao permite percorrer estruturas de. dados aninhadas de forma mas concisa. Aqui esta um exemplo de colo voce pode adaptar seu codigo usando recursao:

```
def percorrer_dict(d):
    for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            percorrer_dict(value)
        else:
            print(f'{key} - {value}')

percorrer_dict(menu_groups)
```

Neste exemplo. definimos uma funçao `percorrer_dict` que recebe um dicionario como argumento. A funçao cada item do dicionario usambo um loop for, verificando se o valor correspondente a cada chave é um dicionario. Se for chamamos recusivamente a funcao `percorrer_dict` para percorrer o dicionariointerno, Caso contrario, imprimimos a chave e o valor.

Esa abordagem nos permite percorrer um dicionario com varias chaves encadeadas sem a necessidade de multiplos loops for. Ela se adapta automaticamente a diferentes niveis de aninhamento, tonrando o codigo mais enxuto e evitando a necessidade de loops adicionais.

Comment: Gostei da sugestão...! Realmente a recursão pode ser uma boa alternativa pra resolver esse tipo de situação. A complexidade tá em definir o caso-base pra finalizar recursão.

Até então tá gerando exceção RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, justamente por não ter conseguido definir o caso-base.

Após chegar numa solução vou avaliar o desempenho e utilização de recurso computacional.